# Allow users to talk with long pauses

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am designing an action where the users are asked to share their thoughts and experiences. For example,

- Agent: What are your thoughts on XYZ?
- User: XYZ seems pretty good. While I am content with its features...[8-10 second pause], I had higher expectations...[10-12 seconds pause]...I
  thought it could allow me to ...
- Agent: Thanks for sharing. Do you have anything else to add?
- User: Hmm...[8 seconds pause]...In general I would say XYZ is a nice tool to ...
- Agent: Thanks your insights. Talk to you later. Bye!

This kind of conversation requires the mic of the Google Home device to be open for a longer time. I think a Google Home device keeps its mic open for 8 seconds by default to listen to the user utterance. This may need to be longer for many use cases such as the one mentioned above.

Currently, when the user pauses even for 3-5 seconds, agent jumps to the next intent.

Is there a way to customize the length of the time that device's mic is open?

I am using Dialogflow and Node.js. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no way to keep the microphone open for a longer period of time. Allowing an open mic for an extended time is a security concern.

The upcoming ["Continuous Match Mode"](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/announcing-actions-builder-actions-sdk.html) may solve this in part, but it will only be available in the Interactive Canvas, and is designed for specific inputs and not free-form inputs (again, for security reasons).

The best workaround in your case is that, when you get input from the user, acknowledge it, and prompt (in some way) that they can continue their thoughts. Only once they say they're done do you give the next prompt.

Comment: Is there any official documentation stating why open mic is a security concern?